# Any alternative to passing a range to a user-defined function?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Since user-defined functions can't be invoked with an argument that varies with the row context, I'm struggling to find an alternative to what I am trying to do.

I have a table which has rows which records session start and end times after the sessions have closed.  I want to be able to visualize the number of connections over time.

I've provided a sample datatable (T) as an example.

The following doesn't work because of user-defined function restrictions.

```
let T = datatable (TimeGenerated:datetime, ConnectionId:string, Start:datetime, End:datetime)
[ datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:58.680Z'), "0001", datetime('2021-02-11T20:20:50.172Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:28.673Z'),
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:58.517Z'), "0002", datetime('2021-02-11T20:04:40.131Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:20:52.742Z'),
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:57.470Z'), "0003", datetime('2021-02-11T20:17:51.585Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:18:41.945Z'),
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:56.793Z'), "0004", datetime('2021-02-11T20:18:04.508Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:19:16.594Z'),
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:55.697Z'), "0005", datetime('2021-02-11T20:15:20.139Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:18:26.688Z')
];
let bins = 1m;
let ConnectionsAtTime = (timestamp:datetime) {
toscalar(
T
| where Start <= timestamp and End >= timestamp
| count
)
};
let fakeNow = datetime('2021-02-11T20:22:00Z');
range timestamp from fakeNow - 5m to fakeNow step bins
| extend Count = ConnectionsAtTime(timestamp)
```

But, if it did work, I would expect the following output:

| timestamp | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2/11/2021, 8:12:00.000 PM | 1 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:13:00.000 PM | 1 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:14:00.000 PM | 1 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:15:00.000 PM | 1 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:16:00.000 PM | 2 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:17:00.000 PM | 2 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:18:00.000 PM | 3 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:19:00.000 PM | 2 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:20:00.000 PM | 1 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:21:00.000 PM | 1 |
| 2/11/2021, 8:22:00.000 PM | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something along the following lines:

```
let T = datatable (TimeGenerated:datetime, ConnectionId:string, Start:datetime, End:datetime)
[ 
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:58.680Z'), "0001", datetime('2021-02-11T20:20:50.172Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:28.673Z'),
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:58.517Z'), "0002", datetime('2021-02-11T20:04:40.131Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:20:52.742Z'),
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:57.470Z'), "0003", datetime('2021-02-11T20:17:51.585Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:18:41.945Z'),
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:56.793Z'), "0004", datetime('2021-02-11T20:18:04.508Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:19:16.594Z'),
  datetime('2021-02-11T20:21:55.697Z'), "0005", datetime('2021-02-11T20:15:20.139Z'), datetime('2021-02-11T20:18:26.688Z')
];
let bins = 1m;
let fakeNow = datetime('2021-02-11T20:22:00Z');
let ConnectionsAtTime = (T:(Start:datetime, End:datetime, ConnectionId:string), range_start:datetime, range_end:datetime, bin:timespan)
{
    T
    | mv-expand timestamp = range(range_start, range_end, bin) to typeof(datetime)
    | summarize dcountif(ConnectionId, Start <= timestamp and End >= timestamp) by timestamp
}
;
T
| invoke ConnectionsAtTime(fakeNow - 5m, fakeNow, bins)
```

-->

| timestamp | countif_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-11 20:17:00.0000000 | 2 |
| 2021-02-11 20:18:00.0000000 | 3 |
| 2021-02-11 20:19:00.0000000 | 2 |
| 2021-02-11 20:20:00.0000000 | 1 |
| 2021-02-11 20:21:00.0000000 | 1 |
| 2021-02-11 20:22:00.0000000 | 0 |